# Pytorch autograd: compute batch gradient w.r.t to input

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I need to compute the gradient of the network output (not the loss) with respect to the input but I'm getting the error `grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs`. I'm trying to reproduce what's described in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.01026v4.pdf) and I need the gradient I mentioned to perform step 7 [image]

This is what I'd like to do:

```
out = netD(input).view(-1)
out.backward(retain_graph=True)
grad = input.grad
```